# Find results based off results using eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table.

**Locations**

```
id | postcode | suburb | state
```

And another table:

**Classifieds**

```
id | name | location - Matches to 'id' in the first table
```

First I have a code which executes and saves the results of the locations from table one into a variable. Next I need to find which of the classifieds match up to the results in the variable. This is what I have so far, not really sure how to do it.

This code runs on the view:

```
$locations = Location::where('location', '=', $_GET['location']); (From the URL)
```

**This code needs to find results in the 'classifieds' table that matches the classified's location id with *ANY* id in the $locations variable**

```
    foreach($locations as $loc)
        {
            foreach($classifieds as $classi)
            {
                if($loc->id == $classi->location)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Something like this ^, except this code doesn't work

To further explain this with an example:

Locations array **variable** has:

98212 | 4220 | BURLEIGH HEADS | QLD (id, postcode, suburb, state)

98213 | 4221 | BURLEIGH WATERS | QLD (id, postcode, suburb, state)

**This is the result of (Classified::where('location, '=', $_GET['location')->get())**

Classifieds table has:

```
1 | Red Bike | 98212 (id, name, location)

2 | Red Bike | 98213 (id, name, location)

3 | Red Bike | 98213 (id, name, location)
```

Find classifieds where the location is listed **within the variable**

Comment: `Location::where('location', ..)` - how does that work, if the `Locations` table doesn't have a `location` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract all location IDs into one array with the `Collection` method `pluck()` or `lists()` (depends on the version):

```php
$locationIds = $locations->pluck(id);
```

and use Eloquents `whereIn()` method:

```php
$classfields = Classified::whereIn('location', $locationIds)->get();
```

That all can be a one-liner:

```php
$classfields = Classified::whereIn('location', $locations->pluck(id))->get();
```

Comment: Had trouble expressing the problem fully but you got it, much appreciated @Paul Spiegel

Comment: If you don't need the *locations* but only the corresponding *classfields*, all could be done with one query passing the locations-query into the *whereIn* function. But i didn't get how your locations-query works.

Comment: The locations are loaded first into an array variable, then the classifieds are based upon the id's in the array variable - which whereIn and array_pluck works